# Kivy Accordion: Not enough space warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, kivy, accordion

I am trying to make an accordion-based menu using Kivy and Python 3.7 in a 1366x768 display (in case it makes a difference). The code seems to work just fine, as I get the desired output. However, I get the warning stating that there is not enough space for all children in the accordion (I presume) and the layout will be aborted, but it is not: everything is drawn with plenty of space. While it is not a critical problem, as everything shows as expected, I am either missing something obvious or have a misconception about how kivy generates screen elements. So if you could clarify this (and hopefully get rid of the ugly warning), I would greatly appretiate it!

Below is a reduced version of the code, all in pure python (I'd like to keep it that way, it's not a complicated program). I just make an external BoxLayout, and inside I place an inner GridLayout with the accordions a button down below. Note that I have kivy set up to run as maximized window, the setting up for this is included in the code.

At first I thought it might be related to the order kivy processes items or something: it may first check the labels and button assuming a default size_hint=(1, 1) and think it does not have space, but then be able to draw them thanks to the custom size_hint. However, when changing this to (1, 1) I got the same warning while still having everything drawn with space to spare (although not a huge lot). It did slightly change the warning though, as it showed more warnings with tighter restrictions.

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.config import Config


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        inner_layout = GridLayout(cols=3)
        inner_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Section 1", size_hint=(1, 0.09), font_size='20dp'))
        inner_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Section 2", size_hint=(1, 0.09), font_size='20dp'))
        inner_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Section 3", size_hint=(1, 0.09), font_size='20dp'))

        accord1 = Accordion(orientation="vertical")
        accord1.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 1"))
        accord1.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 2"))

        accord2 = Accordion(orientation="vertical")
        accord2.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 1"))

        accord3 = Accordion(orientation="vertical")
        accord3.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 1"))
        accord3.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 2"))
        accord3.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 3"))

        inner_layout.add_widget(accord1)
        inner_layout.add_widget(accord2)
        inner_layout.add_widget(accord3)

        layout.add_widget(inner_layout)

        continue_btn = Button(text="START", size_hint=(1, 0.07))
        layout.add_widget(continue_btn)

        return layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Three lines to ensure non-fullscreen, maximized window on launch
    Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 0)
    Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', 0)
    Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')

    Config.write()

    TestApp().run()
```

This is the warning I get with the shown code:

```
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 132px, got 91px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
```

While these are the ones resulting from changing all size_hint values to the default (1, 1):

```
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 88px, got 50px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 132px, got 50px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that warning is that the `Accordion` widget is running its layout code before its actual size is set (normal for `Accordion`). Notice that the message says `need 132px`. That is because the default minimum size for each item is 44, and your `accord3` has 3 children (3 times 44 is 132). It also says `got 91px`. That is because the initial size of the parent `GridLayout` is 100 by 100 (as it is for all widgets), and 0.09 of that (or 9px) is taken by the `Section 3` `Label`, leaving 91px for the `Accordion`. Since 91 is less than 132, it decides that there is not enough space. Correct, but shortly after that, the layout code is called again with correct values and all is well. Would be nice if the authors of that code could eliminate those meaningless warnings.

So, you can avoid those warnings by not adding your `Accordion` widgets to the layout until after the `GridLayout` has determined its real size. to do that, you can use `Clock.schedule_once()`. Here is a modification of your `TestApp` using that approach:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.inner_layout = GridLayout(cols=3)
        self.inner_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Section 1", size_hint=(1, 0.09), font_size='20dp'))
        self.inner_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Section 2", size_hint=(1, 0.09), font_size='20dp'))
        self.inner_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Section 3", size_hint=(1, 0.09), font_size='20dp'))

        layout.add_widget(self.inner_layout)

        continue_btn = Button(text="START", size_hint=(1, 0.07))
        layout.add_widget(continue_btn)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_accordions)

        return layout

    def add_accordions(self, dt):

        accord1 = Accordion(orientation="vertical")
        accord1.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 1"))
        accord1.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 2"))

        accord2 = Accordion(orientation="vertical")
        accord2.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 1"))

        accord3 = Accordion(orientation="vertical")
        accord3.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 1"))
        accord3.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 2"))
        accord3.add_widget(AccordionItem(title="Item 3"))

        self.inner_layout.add_widget(accord1)
        self.inner_layout.add_widget(accord2)
        self.inner_layout.add_widget(accord3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It totally answers the question. I won't bother with the clock solution, since I feel like generating part of the interface later just to avoid meaningless warnings will be more harmful than the warnings themselves. It is a shame that those warnings are there anyway, as with any false positive. Thanks again!